# How to insert lines from one file in the middle of another file using shell scripts

Tags: shell

I intend to copy some lines of a file to a specified location in another file using shell scripts. I only know a command:

```
cat A >> B
```

But, it only works for copying all lines of file A and paste them to the end file B. Instead, I want to insert content from file A in the middle of the file B.

### Example

File A:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

File B:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

Then copy lines 2-3 of file A to the file B after line 2:

```
AAA
BBB
bbb
ccc
CCC
```

In other words, I want to insert some successive lines of a file into another file at any point. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about any command but I have workaround for it,

If you know line no at which you want to add something then why dont you use head and tail commands

suppose you want to aaa in your some file A at line no 3
A is like,

```
AAA

BBB

CCC

DDD
```

then

```
head -n 2 > B   # this will copy first 2 lines 
echo "aaa" >> B # your desired string at line no 3
tail -n 2 >>B  # remaining lines into file
```

instead of tail you can try

```
'sed 1,2d' A >> B
```

or

```
awk 'NR>2' A >> B
```

for writing remaining lines to B

This can be used for smaller files but will be heavy for larger files

Comment: Could you please format your codes using Ctrl + k? It's a bit difficult for me to read it because I am new to shell scripts :-)

Comment: echo "aaa" >> B You use echo directly? I think that's not a graceful way. In fact, it's not my need.

Comment: please elaborate your need in detail with an example may be then I can help you with specifics

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have the standard Linux tools, you can say

```
paste -d "\n" A B
```

Comment: I am afraid it does not come to my aid